# HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink doesn't give expected result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I'm (desperately) trying to create a link from one of my controllers.

It should look like so:
http://localhost:50074/User/Profile?UserId=17&key=agasgqwefq323432r13dfd

The relevant (though probably erroneous) route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "UsersRoute", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{key}",
             new { controller = "User", action = "Profile",userId=UrlParameter.Optional,key=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And the link code:

```
HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink(requestContext, RouteTable.Routes, "MyLinkText", "UsersRoute", new RouteValueDictionary(new { userId = userId, key = HashPassword(password) } ), null);
```

(where I send the request context by:  `HttpContext.Request.RequestContext`.

This currently gives me:

```
<a href="http://Account/Register/29/E96303852080B94DC230611A3F4806" target="_blank">MyLinkText</a>
```

(the context from which I call `GenerateRouteLink` is Account/Register, and I don't know how to create a correct one, if that's really needed)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route definition the url will be of the form:

```
{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{key}
```

so I don't see how can you possibly expect an url of the form (`{controller}/{action}`) when you specify the `userid` and `key` tokens:

```
/User/Profile?UserId=17&key=agasgqwefq323432r13dfd
```

Why don't you simply leave only the default url definition?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you could get urls of the desired form by simply:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "MyLinkText", 
    "Profile", 
    "User", 
    new { userId = userId, key = HashPassword(password) }, 
    null
)
```

Comment: I know how to do that from a View, the problem is I can't do that from cs.. (i.e. a controller)

Comment: @Oren A, in a controller you could use the `Url.Action` method.